# Concept: Build Java Program and load it into Oracle DB - Wrapper function calls java function with return

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Lets say I got following java function:

```
public class Example {

public String getHelloWorld(String hello) {
    return hello + "world"
 }

}
```

I call the method by getHelloWorld("hello") and function gets me "hello world" as a return. Through a starter class (main method only) I instantiate a new "Example", and call the non static function getHelloWorld. Everthing fine here.

Now I want to put this class inside an Oracle Database: With the following command it works as expected; PLSQL:

```
create or replace java source named "com.test.Example" as
public class Example { [...]
```

Now I got the response from the database that the java source was successfully created.

Now I try to right a wrapper function to later call my function from pl/sql: 
`function get_hello_world(i_string VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  LANGUAGE java name 'com.test.Example.getHelloWorld(
                                              java.lang.String
                                              ) return java.lang.String';`

Now I got some questions: Does all this work together? Can I call a non-static method like "getHelloWorld" as I did here in the example?

If only static method is possible, do I need to write a main method? If yes, how can I access the return in PL/SQL? From my point of view, a main method does not have a return..

Could someone give me any clues to get a solution?

Comment: what happens when you *execute* it?

Comment: ORA-29531: no method getHelloWorldin class [..] Error, wrapper function compiled and is valid, as well as java source

Comment: is the compiled source up to date?

Comment: Yes it is, to verify the state of the source, I logged out of database and reconnected to it. And in addition, I did not forget to commit after each step, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working with the help of all of you! With the help of a more specific ticket [ORA-29531: no method in class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507453/ora-29531-no-method-in-class-error/50508713?noredirect=1#comment88029789_50508713) I was able to fix my problem. The you @MTO for bringing up the rights thought. If somebody is interested in my solution, look at the answer at this the linked ticket.

Key-Parts:

1. Be sure the java library is successfully loaded into the Database. Either by the pl/sql command as I described in my question. But there is always the chance that your desired library is already loaded into your database, but you didn't know. To verify this fact, use `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE LIKE '%JAVA%' AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%ColognePhonetic%'`
2. You can't run non-static functions directly! Be sure to write an static function, where you just instantiate the object of the none-satic function and call the desired function. Example:

   `create or replace java source named "com.test.Example" AS 
   public class Example { 
    public String getHelloWorld ( final String hello ) { 
      return hello + "world" }
    public static String getStaticHelloWorld(final String hello){
      final Example e = new Example();
      return e.getHelloWorld( hello );
    }
   }`
3. Write an Wrapper function, which start your newly created static function.

   `CREATE FUNCTION get_hello_world(i_string VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
   LANGUAGE java name 'com.test.Example.getStaticHelloWorld(
     java.lang.String
   ) return java.lang.String';`
4. Be sure, to call your PL/SQL function the right way! `declare
   result varchar2(20);
   begin
   -- Call the function
   result := get_hello_world('hello');
   end;` or SQL:

`select get_hello_world('hello') from dual;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to call a static method, but within the static method you can create an instance of the class and call non-static methods:

```
create or replace java source named "com.test.Example" AS
public class Example {
  public String getHelloWorld(
    final String hello
  ) {
    return hello + "world"
  }

  public static String getStaticHelloWorld(
    final String hello;
  ){
    final Example e = new Example();
    return e.getHelloWorld( hello );
  }
}
/

CREATE FUNCTION get_hello_world(i_string VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  LANGUAGE java name 'com.test.Example.getStaticHelloWorld(
      java.lang.String
    ) return java.lang.String';
```