# ORA-29531: no method in class error

Tags: java, oracle, apache, plsql

I try to write an Wrapper function in PL/SQl to call the encode function of the org.apache.commons.codec.language.colognephonetic Class, as described on official apache commons wiki. [Cologne Phonetic Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/ColognePhonetic.html)

Wrapper function looks like following:

```
  function get_phonetic_string(i_string VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE java name 'org.apache.commons.codec.language.ColognePhonetic.encode(
                                          java.lang.String
                                          ) return java.lang.String';
```

But, when I execute my wrapper function, I got following error: **ORA-29531: no method encode in class org/apache/commons/codec/language/ColognePhonetic**. But obviously there is a encode function.

Could someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used the `loadjava` application to load the jar file into the database? Have you checked the contents of the jar file before you uploaded it into the database to make sure it contains the referenced class file and made sure that the version of the class contains that method? Can you write a minimal class in an external IDE that uses the jar file in the way that you want to use it to make sure it works outside the database (and that it is a database/configuration issue rather than a java/missing file issue)?

Comment: This class was loaded into the database automatically because its a standard library for apache common so they get loaded by the installation of the Database. I could imagine it has something to do how the function is called as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504506/concept-build-java-program-and-load-it-into-oracle-db-wrapper-function-calls/50507814#50507814

Comment: I like the second part of your answer, I'll try it and answer afterwords.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE LIKE '%JAVA%' AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%ColognePhonetic%'` gives me zero results - do not assume that the library has been automatically included. You will probably have to use the `loadjava` application to load it manually.

Comment: Thank you for the query, on our database we got 4 entries by running this query. So these should not be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the `org.apache.commons.codec.language.ColognePhonetic` class is in the database (it probably will not be).

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  OBJECT_TYPE LIKE '%JAVA%'
AND    LOWER( OBJECT_NAME ) LIKE '%colognephonetic%';
```

Should return a row if it exists (may need to be run as a privileged user).

If it does not exist then you will need to use the `loadjava` application to load the jar library containing the classes.

Then write a wrapper to create a static function that makes an instance of the class (*untested*):

```
CREATE JAVA SOURCE NAMED Phonetics AS
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.ColognePhonetic;

public class Phonetics {
  public static String encode(
    final String text
  ){
    final ColognePhonetic cp = new ColognePhonetic();
    return cp.encode( text );
  }
}
/

CREATE FUNCTION get_phonetic_string(i_string VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Phonetics.encode( java.lang.String ) return java.lang.String';
```

Comment: Thats exactely what I was looking for, and by the way, all I was trying to do the last hour :) Thank you very much! However, I'm not able to create java source as you described. Did you test your solution? If yes, on which java version? We got java 1.7.

Comment: @Ronaldo-CH As I said in the answer - it is untested (as I do not have the classes loaded into my Oracle instance, and am not going to do that, so I will never be able to get it to work). Running `SHOW ERRORS;` after creating the java source or using `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS` should help you debug the issue.

Comment: final String text; -> the ; was to much, now its working, thank you again! safed my day!